# Strange outlet behavior

Tags: electrical, receptacle, grounding

I am going to be updating electrical outlets in my house, so today I checked them all with the 3 lamp tester.  Only a few are properly grounded and others not.  One outlet is showing strange behavior.

If washer is connected to the lower outlet, the upper shows proper grounding (lamps 2 & 3 are ON).  But if I disconnect the washer and check again, only 2nd lamp is ON indicating no proper grounding.  Is connecting the washer doing something funny with both receptacles?

Update:

1. When the washer is connected to a GFCI outlet, it runs uninterrupted without tripping that outlet. I have tested that the GFCI outlet is working as expected (the reset test).
2. I tested the original non-GFCI outlet in my question with a second 3 prong equipment (a grain mill) and now the receptacle tester illuminates only the middle lamp (i.e. no grounding) as expected.

So it looks like there is definitely some grounding fault with the washer but that doesn't stop it from working either on GFCI or non-GFCI outlets.

Update 2:

1. It looks like my GFCI receptacle may be wired incorrectly. I can't get it to trip with gfci receptacle tester. In stead, when I press the tester switch, it lights up first and last lamps indicating that neutral and hot are reversed.  I will post another update when I open up the outlet to check.

Comment: What are lamps 2 and 3

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. Lamps on the receptacle tester.

Comment: Does the washer have a neutral-ground fault?

Comment: Yes, does the washer trip a GFCI when you plug it into one and start the washing cycle?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Noted.  I am in the United States.

Comment: Does the washer have a metal water line? It could be grounding through that.

Comment: @LShaver Yes, both the cold and hot water supply lines are metal braided if that's what you mean.  This would make sense because I am pretty sure my second main grounding (for the house) is connected to my plumbing somewhere.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - if a GFCI is wired backwards, can you still make it reset?

Comment: @Mazura backwards as in "line/load swapped" or backwards as in "hot/neutral swapped"?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Line/Load. GFCIs won't reset w/o power. OP says it doesn't trip, but it does test, so it 'resets'. I don't see how, otherwise, it would run w/o tripping if the washer has a fault.

Comment: I should mention that I used the GFCI outlet in the bathroom which is piggybacking on the bathroom lamp. How do I know this? GFCI is OFF unless lamp is ON.

Comment: All moot points anyway imo. If the washer has a fault, you'll find out after (arbitrarily, or not) replacing that GFCI and having inspected/replaced every other outlet on the circuit. I would think a properly installed gfci and a washer that doesn't pop it should eliminate all concerns. Those testers can give you false readings if you don't unload the circuit (unplug everything).

Comment: "Open ground" doesn't mean a ground fault; it means you need to start opening up boxes.

Comment: check the plug wiring within the washer and make sure someone didn't move the chassis ground wire coming from inside the washer to the neutral lug?

Answer (score 6):

This feels like the washing machine has a ground fault, where there's a connection between neutral and earth somewhere. See [Why does my laundry machine trip the GFCI when I plug it in?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/104256/why-does-my-laundry-machine-trip-the-gfci-when-i-plug-it-in)

If so, this is something you need to deal with, as it makes using your washing machine unsafe.

(In that case, when the tester checks for ground, power goes into the earth pin, up the earth pin on the washer, out the neutral pin on the washer, and back into the panel, which looks a lot like a real ground.)

You can also test with a different three-pin device connected, and see if you still get a fake earth reading.

EDIT: since you tested with a GFCI, and it works, I'll take another look with the new information.

When you plug in the washer, the 3rd light comes on. The usual meaning for the third light is that there's a voltage difference between hot to ground, which means the ground is going somewhere. While it's possible there's a grounding wire somewhere that you missed, another interesting possibility is that the surface the washing machine rests on is acting as a ground. This is somewhat dependent on the surface and the actual construction of the washing machine, but if the washer feet are metal, and it's resting on concrete, there might be enough conductivity to give a ground reading. In that case, your tester is giving a correct result. (But you should still run a real earth wire.)

Comment: You could use a long extension cord to plug the washer into a GFCI receptacle to test for a ground fault.

Comment: You should note that not only is the washer faulty, but the missing ground should also be fixed. Probably obvious, but hey...

Comment: There is infinite resistance (reading of 1) between the GROUND and NEUTRAL/HOT plugs of the washer.  Does that mean my washer is OK? I also checked both the outlets with multimeter and neither are properly grounded.

Comment: @JimStewart Is that safe to do? The cord clearly says not to use extension cord.

Comment: @cryptic0 if you use a heavy duty cable and only have the washer on long enough to see if it trips the GFCI you'll be OK.  The danger is that if you use a light weight extension cord (think lamp cable) and run a full wash cycle you'll overheat the cable and have a fire hazard.  Heavy duty cords are made with thicker wires to carry heavy draws; and for the test you only need the washer on briefly; because if there's an electrical fault the GFCI should promptly shut everything down.

Comment: Concerning the infinite resistance between neutral and hot on the washer plug, I'm sure the washer was off and unplugged when you determined this, right? There should be infinite resistance because the internal power switch is open (off).

Comment: @JimStewart Indeed.  I am not sure how to do that resistance test while the washer is powered up.

Comment: When you got the fake ground reading, was the washer turned on and operating?

Comment: Sounds to me like the washer is grounded through the water line.

Comment: @user3757614 Good point. Washer was OFF when I took the reading.  But it behaves the same way when it's turned ON.

Comment: @LShaver If that's indeed the case, is it NEC code compliant?

Comment: @cryptic0 almost certainly not NEC compliant -- just a theory about what's going on.

Comment: If there's a ground fault, why isn't it popping the GFCI? "Update: When the washer is connected to a GFCI outlet, it runs uninterrupted without tripping that outlet."